# Get values from the elements those don't have class attribute with the help of xpath

Tags: python, html, css, xpath, scrapy

i want to fetch those elements value who have not attribute name like class, i tried many times with different code with the help of xpath but not reaching to success. please help me out.thanks in advance.

[image]

> my code

```
response.xpath("//select/option[count(@class)=0]/text()").extract()
```

> html tags to fetch the values

```html
   <select name="skuAndSize" class="nsg-form--drop-down exp-pdp-size-dropdown exp-pdp-dropdown two-column-dropdown selectBox" data-tooltiptext="Select a Size" required="required" data-error="Select a Size" data-has-fixed-ancestor="true" style="display: none;">
      <option class="exp-pdp-size-not-in-stock" value=""></option>
      <option name="skuId" value="17401288:40" data-label="(EU 40)">EU 40</option>
      <option name="skuId" value="17401287:40.5" data-label="(EU 40.5)">EU 40.5</option>
      <option name="skuId" value="17401286:41" data-label="(EU 41)">EU 41</option>
      <option name="skuId" value="17401285:42" data-label="(EU 42)">EU 42</option>
      <option name="skuId" value="17401284:42.5" data-label="(EU 42.5)">EU 42.5</option>
      <option name="skuId" value="17401283:43" data-label="(EU 43)">EU 43</option>
      <option name="skuId" value="17401282:44" data-label="(EU 44)">EU 44</option>
      <option name="skuId" value="17401281:44.5" data-label="(EU 44.5)">EU 44.5</option>
      <option name="skuId" value="17401280:45" data-label="(EU 45)">EU 45</option>
      <option name="skuId" value="17401279:45.5" data-label="(EU 45.5)">EU 45.5</option>
      <option name="skuId" value="17401295:46" data-label="(EU 46)">EU 46</option>
      <option name="skuId" value="17401294:47" data-label="(EU 47)">EU 47</option>
      <option class="exp-pdp-size-not-in-stock selectBox-disabled" name="skuId" value="17401293:47.5" data-label="(EU 47.5)">EU 47.5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Instead of **count(@class)=0** try **not(@class)**. Should work (I haven't tested, but that's what I would write).

Comment: Thanks @PrathameshSarang for your reply, but did not work. i tried many times.

Comment: can you share how you get the response, I have tried your html to my local file, it works with `response.xpath("//select/option[not(@class)]/text()")`

Comment: Dear Mr. @Tiny.D when i use the extract() then it gives all values. if i am not using extract then it gives only values that i need.

`response.xpath("//select/option[not(@class)]/text()").extract()`

Comment: so `response.xpath("//select/option[not(@class)]/text()")` is working for you?

Comment: yes it is working, but sir i need the values from option. it gives the whole data in this shape.
**<Selector xpath='//select/option[not(@class)]/text()' data=u'\n                    \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  EU 40\n   '>**

Comment: **this is my code**
`test = response.xpath("//select/option[not(@class)]/text()")
for i in test:
 print(i)`

Comment: can you share how you get the `response`? I need it to repeat your case

Comment: @Tiny.D Sir, basically i am simply scrap the select element. in select element there are some opitons, some options are disabled so i avoid the disabled values only want to get the enable option values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to filter option without attr `class`, the url address content have another select and option without class, the text is also 47.5, that's why you fond the last one is 47.5, you could filter with select `name='skuAndSize'` like this:

```
response.xpath("//select[@name='skuAndSize']/option[not(@class)]/text()").extract()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: url to scrap. [http://store.nike.com/ae/en_gb/pd/lunarepic-low-flyknit-2-running-shoe/pid-11235196/pgid-11649671]

Comment: Sir, superb Thanks for your kind attention. please can you tell me i was just using  `soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, '?')` in second parameter i dont know what i will use. **lxml, html.parser etc** not working.

Comment: If the answer is solution, please mark it as accept answer. Normally **lxml, html.parser** is basic two paser for bs4 to use, should work.

Comment: what is your `html_doc`?

Comment: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` not working in cmd line. how i will use this.

Comment: I think you have to install bs4 before you use it, refer to official doc [link](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144370/discussion-between-muhammad-zia-ur-rahman-and-tiny-d).